# Protractor: Checking to see if a link contains certain text. Expected [ true, true ] to be [ true, true ]

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I'm testing to see that if a user has a currency of "EUR" and another currency of "GBP" displayed at the top of the page, I'm then expecting that a link containing the text "EUR" and another link containing text "GBP" is present further down the page. This is contained in a div called `"nav-tabs au-target"`
When I run my script I get the following error:
`Expected [ true, true ] to be [ true, true ]`

This is my page object file:

```js
if(text.indexOf("EUR") >-1 && text.indexOf("GBP") >-1){
expect(element.all(by.linkText("EUR"&&"GBP")).isDisplayed())
.toBe([true, true]);
console.log("EUR AND GBP buyer");}
```

I've tried to see if `"nav-tabs au-target"` contains link text "EUR" and "GBP" instead of element.all but struggling to get it to work
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably not a problem with Protactor or your app but rather with incorrect usage of a Jasmine's API.

In particular:

```
expect(actualValue).toBe(expectedValue)
```

will do following check:

```
actualValue === expectedValue
```

which won't work for objects or arrays.

For object or arrays, you should use `toEqual` instead of `toBe` which will perform a deep comparison between two values.

You can see this in action in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyfmbegc/).

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer was helpful, consider marking it as correct so it won't appear in "unanswered" section.